# Joomla module/component for table administration

Tags: joomla

My client's website runs on Joomla and they would like me to add some custom functionality to the site.

It is a quotation system, so they will just need to be able to update the values that are used to caluclate the quote. So there would only need to be 4 parts to this:

1. Settings page in the admin section
2. Database table that stores the settings
3. Front end form
4. PHP script to process the form / query the database table

If I was not using a CMS I could easily accomplish this task but my client would like this system to be integrated with Joomla. Can anyone advise how I should approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this easily with Chronoforms and Chrono Connectivity from Chrono Engine. Use the Chronoforms to create the forms that access the data and Connectivity to display and edit the data.

Forms - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508
Connectivity - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/faq/5661

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) it will allow you to get started writing your logic.